# Suppose that $A=I_T −X(X′X)^{−1}X′$ where $X$ is a $T\times k$ matrix.

Tags: matrices

a) Find $Tr [A]$

b) Show that $A$ is symmetric

c) Show that $A$ is idempotent.

d) Hence show that the eigenvalues of $A$ are either zero or one.

e) Hence show that $r[A] = Tr[A]$.

Comment: For (a) use the [cyclic property of trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Cyclic_property). For (b) and (c), check directly that the definition of "symmetric" and "idempotent" hold. For (d), think about how the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are related to the eigenvalues of $A$. For (e), think about how rank and trace are related to eigenvalues.

Comment: Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is explained [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to address the following. Where did you find this question? What are your thoughts on the question? What have you tried so far?